# Informatica filter based on the date column on the other table in the different database?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica 10.2, I have requirement to filter the data on the main table based on the other table value which is in the different database.

**Scenario :**

**Table1 (Db1**)

```
  Column in the tables: Name, Age, salary, last_updated
```

**Table2 (Db2)**

```
  Column in the tables: Tablename, last_pull_time, NoofRecords
```

Assume Table2 always return one row (based on the where clause it always return 1 row for the specified table name)

Now in the target, I need to load the data of Table1 but I need to filter the data based on the last_pull_time (Table)

**Condition :**

```
  Table1.last_updated > Table2.last_pull_time
```

How to achieve this filter since both the tables are in different database?

Note: I'm new to Informatica

Comment: sorry for the typo - Condition should be - Table1.last_updated > Table2.last_pull_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it thriugh below process,

1. Get Table1 as source in the Mapping
2. Import Table2 as unconnected lookup. Use table_name as join condition.
3. In expression transformation, pass table_name as argument and return the value of lookup which is last_pull_time
4. Use filter transformation to filter the records Table1.last_updated > lookup's result
5. Pass it to the target

   ```
   Source --> Expression --> Filter --> Target <br>
                ^
                |  
              Lookup
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Approach looks good, going to try this.